# nargs depending on another setting?

Tags: python, command-line, argparse

I'm trying to write a program that supports arbitrary bitwise opertions: AND, OR, NOT and COUNT for bitmaps. The usage is that you run `program.py --and f1.bit f2.bit` and it prints you the result to the stdout.

The problem is that I'd like the parser to handle all the caveats. Specifically, I'd like the nargs to depend on the mode that's set - if it's set to COUNT or NOT, exactly one file is expected, if it's set to OR or AND, expect exactly two. Here's some (non-working) example code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import argparse

def main(mode, fnames):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-O', '--or',
        nargs=2,
        action='store_const', const='or'
    )
    args = parser.parse_args()

    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(args.__dict__)

    #main(**args.__dict__)
```

And the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bitmaptool.py", line 12, in <module>
    action='store_const', const='or'
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/argparse.py", line 1362, in add_argument
    action = action_class(**kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'nargs'
```

Commenting out `nargs` helps, as does leaving `nargs` out but commenting out `action` - but I want both. Do I need to implement it manually or is there a trick or another library that would let me get there?

**EDIT** I wanted to clarify what I'm looking for by showing what code I needed to write manually for the thing to work:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
    parser.add_argument('-O', '--or', nargs=2)
    parser.add_argument('-A', '--and', nargs=2)
    parser.add_argument('-M', '--minus', nargs=2)
    parser.add_argument('-C', '--count', nargs=1)
    parser.add_argument('-N', '--not', nargs=1)
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', default='/dev/stdout')
    args = parser.parse_args().__dict__

    mode = None
    files = []
    for current_mode in ['or', 'and', 'not', 'count']:
        if current_mode in args:
            if mode is not None:
                sys.exit('ERROR: more than one mode was specified')
            mode = current_mode
            files = args[mode]

    if mode is None:
        sys.stderr.write('ERROR: no mode was specified\n\n')
        parser.print_help()
        sys.exit(1)

    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(args)
```

Is there a more elegant way to get there?

Comment: @DJSchaffner nope, doesn't help. It wouldn't really make sense either though - keep in mind that kwargs can appear in any order, provided they're after args.

Comment: With `store_const`, `nargs` is set to 0, so you can't add your own value.  But why do you want to store a "or" string when the argument's flag is '--or'.  You don't want `args.or=="or"` do you?

Comment: @hpaulj I want to be able to do `program.py --or f1.bit f2.bit` and have `mode="or"` and filenames stored elsewhere

Comment: Argparse will store that as (in dictionary form) `{'or': ['f1.bit','f2.bit']}`.  'or' is the `key`, a list of names the value.

Comment: You could also use the `subcommands` approach, as described in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

`store_const` **never** gets arguments, it literally stores what you stated as `const` or `None`. Because it's a constant, not a variable. From the [argparse's `action` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action), ephasis mine:

> `'store_const'` - This **stores the value specified by the const keyword argument**. The `'store_const'` action is most commonly used with optional arguments that specify **some sort of flag**.

You should change the action to something that will actually store the filenames passed. As per [argparse's `nargs` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) and example, you actually don't need to specify `action` at all, default (`action='store'`) will suffice.

Example from documentation:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('--foo', nargs=2) #this line
>>> parser.add_argument('bar', nargs=1)
>>> parser.parse_args('c --foo a b'.split())
Namespace(bar=['c'], foo=['a', 'b'])
```

---

**EDIT** for the edited version of the question - [mutually exclusive group](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion) will make sure only one argument (from that group, of course) is specified:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(argument_default=argparse.SUPPRESS)
    parser.add_argument('-o', '--output', default='/dev/stdout')

    group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    group.add_argument('-O', '--or', nargs=2)
    group.add_argument('-A', '--and', nargs=2)
    group.add_argument('-M', '--minus', nargs=2)
    group.add_argument('-C', '--count', nargs=1)
    group.add_argument('-N', '--not', nargs=1)

    args = parser.parse_args().__dict__

    import pprint
    pprint.pprint(args)
```

Comment: I modified my question in order to clarify what I'm looking for. I hope it now explains why your solution unfortunately doesn't seem to be enough. Apologies for the confusion!

Comment: Your "one that more mode was specified" = Mutually exclusive group - https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#mutual-exclusion ;) with `required=True` makes sure you get exactly one argument from that group

Comment: Nice, that only leaves the following part: `mode = None; for current_mode in ['or', 'and', 'not', 'count']: if current_mode in args: mode = current_mode`. I assume it's not possible in argparse as it is right now?

Comment: With the thing you do, you get a dictionary, right? With keys being arguments and values being... well, values. And we fixed the thing so that we always get two arguments  (`output` and the desired operation) and its values. So the mode is literally the only key in that dictionary. ;) `mode = [key for key in args if key != 'output'][0]` is a one-liner that looks weird but works (it literally filters out keys that are not 'output' - thus leaving only the key we want)

Comment: Also: `output = args['output']` and `input_files = args[mode]`. Now you have `mode`, `output` and `input_files` and you don't have to search for them anymore in the `args`. ;)

Comment: Yes, that could work, but it's inelegant for two reasons: 1. if I now add xor, nor or any other new bitwise operation, I have to remember to mention its name in one more place, 2. adding extra options, such as --output, --version etc require a blacklist of modes, which is also a bit smelly. Anyway, thanks for the advice so far!

Comment: The example of finding mode doesn't require you to specify `xor` etc. outside of the `add_argument`. As for the version, it's a special action that returns afterwards, so it doesn't appear in the dict. But, yeah, either them or the omitted ones would need to be specified somewhere in this case. Your try also specified this and you forgot 'minus'...

Comment: 1. You could use a partial parser with the group only - things parsed by it would only have the mode and input files. 2. You could probably make some kind of configuration dictionary in one place for the modes. and then create the group in a loop from it. "Mode list" would be just taken from that dictionary.